# Clone a URI Eclipse 4.3

Tags: android, eclipse, git, egit

on eclipse I want to import an existing project from github. I try to File -> Import... -> Clone URI ->

but the next button does do anything. what should i do now? PS I am on ubuntu 10.04.

I don't have a working ssl key and need to use the https connection.

edit: ok so it's not that the button is disabled but doesn't work. here's the screen shot.[image]

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of the wizard where next is disabled?

Comment: It doesn't work, because maybe it isn't the way you are supposed to import a project form GitHub. I illustrated in my answer an alternative way to clone a GitHub repo with Egit.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the [Egit GitHub tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#GitHub_Tutorial), and **[clone a GitHub repo](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Starting_from_existing_Git_Repositories)** through:

```
Import > Git > Projects from Git > Clone > Next
```

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/5/5a/Egit-0.9-import-projects-select-repository.png]

You can then enter the https url or your repo:

[image: http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/3/35/Egit-0.9-clone-wizard-url-page.png]

---

The [OP Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1516132/dan) describes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748026/clone-a-uri-eclipse-4-3/19750725#comment29758233_19750725) a simpler solution:

> **I ended up just re-installing Eclipse 4.3 and that seems to have cleared up all the problems**.

Comment: Thanks for the help I appreciate it. I ended up just re-installing Eclipse 4.3 and that seems to have cleared up all the problems.

Comment: @Dan: Great! I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.